# Print code-fenced sections of a Markdown document

Tags: console, markdown, awk

*Original code and demo at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wchargin/e371d4f3047cf5d89e7ff9bb47224243).*

Given a Markdown document like

````markdown
Here is some text,
and some more text.
```javascript
const message = "This is JavaScript!";
```
More text follows, and then
```javascript
console.log(message);
```
````

I want to print out the sections in code fences, not including the code
fences, separated by a single blank line:

```
const message = "This is JavaScript!";

console.log(message);
```

I came up with the following AWK script, which seems to do the job
nicely:

````
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { in_code_block = 0 }
/^```/ {
    if (!in_code_block) {
        in_code_block = 1;
        first_line = 1;
    } else {
        in_code_block = 0;
        print "";
    }
}
{
    if (in_code_block && !first_line) {
        print;
    }
    first_line = 0;
}
````

A goal is for the script to be dependency-minimal. I don't want to have
to install an implementation of CommonMark or an Erlang environment. AWK
fits this bill well.

Correspondingly, a non-goal is for this script to be correct in all
cases: I’m happy to accept false positives on lines starting with
```` ```inline code``` like this ````, and similar edge cases.

I’m mostly looking for critique of my AWK, with respect to which I am a
total newbie. But any comments are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten the code with the `next` statement , which skips the current line.

See in GNU.org AWK manual [Next-Statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html).

Also you can use your variable as a condition to the command without additional `if()` inside.

````
BEGIN { in_code_block = 0 }
/^```/ {
        if (in_code_block)
            print "";
        in_code_block = ! in_code_block;
        next
}
in_code_block { print; }
````

Tested with GNU Awk 4.1.3.

Comment: This is great! "Skip this record" is a better description of what I want to do than "toggle this flag". Thanks.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it includes, IMO, the most readable code. oliv's answer is indeed very cute and a nice one-liner to have in my pocket, but requires some thought to figure out what is going on. This one should be readable even to people who don't know AWK. Thanks to all answerers—I learned something from each. :-)

Answer (score 6):

While your code looks ok, it could be improved greatly by making use of `RS` (record separator) and `NR` number of record, provided you're using GNU `awk`.

````
 awk -v RS='```[a-z]*\n' '(NR+1)%2' file
````

In this case `RS` is set such that it is catching everything between triple backticks with optional text.

The only `awk` statement is to print one record out of two.

Comment: This is very cute. gawk is required so that a multi-character `RS` is treated as a regular expression, as opposed to having unspecified behavior, correct? (I note that this also removes all text after the closing \`\`\`, which is fine with me.) One question: why does using ````RS='^```[a-z]*\n'```` (added start-of-line anchor) not work?

Comment: `RS` is by default set to `\n` which means every line is an `awk` record. Changing `RS` changes the meaning of `^` and `$` because you possibly have multi-lines record (which is the case here). So you cannot use `^` in `RS` in this case, but you could use `RS='\n```[a-z]*\n'`

Comment: @wchargin I don't get you comment _I note that this also removes all text after the closing ```_  All text after a closing should backtick should not be printed, or did I miss something?

Comment: It's fine for text after a closing backtick to not be printed—this is what my original implementation did. Technically, a closing code fence may only be followed by whitespace [(demo)](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=Text%0A%60%60%60js%0Acode%0A%60%60%60and_more%0Acode%0A%60%60%60%0AMore%20text), but this is the kind of restriction that I'm happy to drop. Regarding `RS`: it sounds like `^` is matching beginning-of-document, not beginning-of-line, which is only slightly surprising to me. Good to know, in any case.

Answer (score 4):

The Code looks perfect to me.

I thought about using the flip-flop operator, but since you take additional action at the beginning and the end of the code block, this may be difficult in this case.

````
/^```/, /^```/ { ... }
````

Maybe you want to experiment with that idea nevertheless. It may prove valuable in the future.

Comment: This is good to know; thanks! It looks like these are called "range patterns". I'll keep them in mind.